# In SQL, what is the relation between the "with" clause and views?

Tags: sql

I'm reading about views in SQL, and I'm confused about the interplay between views(I know they're used for security reasons), and the `with` clause(used to define  "a temporary view whose definition is available only to the query in which the with clause occurs" [Database System Concepts 5th ed.])
) ).

```
WITH max_balance(value) AS
SELECT MAX(balance)
FROM account
SELECT account_number
FROM account, max_balance
WHERE account.balance = max_balance.value
```

Comment: `with` as in `with check` or `with` to define a CTE?

Comment: Yes,  to define a CTE (common table expression )

Comment: See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739287/mysql-possible-to-join-a-table-against-a-provided-static-list-of-data/7739912#7739912

Comment: Oops, yes, corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views are actually used for several reasons. The two most common are:

- Security, to allow users to see data without seeing the underlying tables
- Simplification, to store a `SELECT` query as an object and be able to treat the result set as a table

From your question I'm assuming you are referring to `CTE`s which are normally written as:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Stuff...
  FROM Table
  WHERE things

)
```

A CTE is essentially a disposable view - it only persists until the **NEXT QUERY**.  After the next query, it no longer can be referenced.

CTEs are primarily used for simplification of complicated data sets and for recursion.